# Highcharts.js: Customization of Funnel

Tags: highcharts

I make a funnel with this script

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'funnel',
            marginRight: 100
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Sales funnel',
            x: -50
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                    softConnector: false
                },
                neckWidth: '2%',
                neckHeight: '0%',

                //-- Other available options
                //height: pixels or percent
                width: '100%'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Unique users',
            data: [
                ['Item 1',   15005],
                ['Item 2',       1681],
                ['Item 3', 1254],
                ['Item 4',    1165],
                ['Item 5',    800],
                ['Item 6',    60],
                ['Item 7',    202],
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fainz777/j7p76n6r/1/

If it possible to make it to this view http://c2n.me/38zvhae ?
Each bar have equal height and only width depends on value.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in Highcharts API to make that chart. Funnel type chart has only one change in width from tapered to straight.

Instead you can try to use area range type chart.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rb4j0unv/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'arearange',
            inverted: true,
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            data: [{low:-100, high:100, x: 0},{low:-50, high:50, x: 1}]
        },{
            data: [{low:-50, high:50, x: 1},{low:-40, high:40, x: 3}]
        },{
            data: [{low:-40, high:40, x: 3},{low:0, high:0, x: 4}]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very nice. But I prefer `inverted: false`.